# Use javassist to modify fields that use getters and setters in a class constructor

Tags: java, constructor, javassist

I am trying to modify the following fields in a class constructor using javassist :

```
Label Label1 = new Label(new StringBuilder().append(user.name));
Label Label2 = new Label(new StringBuilder().append(user.time.toString());
```

I want to prepend text to the 2 labels. The text can be accessed and set using getText() and setText().

How could I achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

The simplest approach is to use the ability to modify the constructor body with java code and let javassist create the bytecode.

So you can easily do something like:

```
ClassPool classPool = ClassPool.getDefault();
CtClass ctClass = classPool.get("package1.package2.ClassToInject");
    /* Notice that in this case I'm going for the default constructor
     * If you want another constructor you just have to materialize the CtClass, for
     * each parameter and pass them in the CtClass Array
     */
CtConstructor declaredConstructor = ctClass.getDeclaredConstructor(new CtClass[] {}); 
 /* Now that you have your constructor you can use insertAfter(), this means, it 
      * will be the last thing to be executed in the constructor. We'll rewrite the 
      * label1 field with our new value. Notice that the string in insertAfter 
      * argument is a regular, valid java code line.
      */
    declaredConstructor.insertAfter("Label1 = new package3.package4.Label(new StringBuilder().append(\"somePrefixMayBeAStringOrAVariableInScope\").append(user.name));");

    // and finally we write the bytecode
ctClass.writeFile("/somePathToPutTheInjectedClassFile/");
```

Also keep in mind that if the prefix you'll be adding, instead of a String is a static field in other class you must give the full qualified name of that class, for example: `.append(package1.package2.SomeClass.SomeField)`.

This is needed because `imports` are only at source level, when you look at the JVM bytecode all class references are to the full qualified name.

More information on how to achieve this kind of modifications with Javassist can be found in the javasssist's documentation, section [4.1 Inserting source text at the beginning/end of a method body](http://www.csg.ci.i.u-tokyo.ac.jp/~chiba/javassist/tutorial/tutorial2.html#before)

**UPDATE**

Whenever you are writing Java code for javassist to inject, keep in mind that you must use full qualified class names, otherwise javassist's classpool wouldn't be able to find the classes resulting in a `javassist.CannotCompileException`.

Comment: Instead of `getDeclaredConstructor`, I used `getConstructors()[0]` since there is only one constructor. Trying to change the index and getting an ArrayOutOfBoundException seems to indicate that this part works.

However, `insertAfter` yields the following error :
Exception in thread "main" javassist.CannotCompileException: [source error] no such class: Label

Comment: @user922764: that's because javassist's classpool cannot find the class `Label` you must define the full class name, like `new package1.package2.Label(....)`. I've edited the answer to reflect that detail.

Comment: Unfortunately, that did not work either.
The documentation says that "Accessing local variables declared in the method is not allowed". The Labels are declared inside the constructor but are themselves not retained as attributes of the class. Instead, they are added to a layout which itself is an attribute of the class.
So it seems that I will have to go through that layout to access the Labels.
Sorry I did not specify this before, I just noticed it.

It's getting complicated :(

Comment: Can you edit your question in order to add the full constructor code that way it will be easier to guide you. Even though you had the `Label1 label = new Label` I had wrongly thought they were class attributes.