# Getting errors when use javassist to modify the class

Tags: java, constructor, bytecode, javassist

I am using javassist 3.19.0-GA jar file to modify the constructor body with java code . This is my code

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.javassist</groupId>
    <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
    <version>3.19.0-GA</version>
</dependency>
```

and java file

```
package org.springframework.aop.framework;

import javassist.ClassPool;
import javassist.CtClass;
import javassist.CtConstructor;
import javassist.LoaderClassPath;
import org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext;

public class JavassistApplication extends XmlWebApplicationContext {

    static {
        ClassPool classPool = ClassPool.getDefault();
        try {
            ClassLoader classLoader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
            classPool.appendClassPath(new LoaderClassPath(classLoader));
            CtClass cc = classPool.get("org.springframework.aop.framework.ProxyCreatorSupport");
            /*modify the constructor body with java code*/
            CtConstructor c = cc.getConstructors()[0];
            c.insertAfter("$0.aopProxyFactory = new org.springframework.aop.framework.JavassistAopProxyFactory();");
             /*Here getting exceptions when i run*/
            cc.toClass();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new IllegalStateException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

and code for JavassistAopProxyFactory() :

```
package org.springframework.aop.framework;
import org.springframework.aop.SpringProxy;
import org.springframework.util.ClassUtils;
import java.io.Serializable;

public class JavassistAopProxyFactory implements AopProxyFactory, Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -37444691555886L;
    // Whether the Javassist library is present on the classpath
    private static final boolean javassistAvailable =
            ClassUtils.isPresent("javassist.ClassPool", JavassistAopProxyFactory.class.getClassLoader());


    public AopProxy createAopProxy(AdvisedSupport config) throws AopConfigException {
        if (config.isOptimize() || config.isProxyTargetClass() || hasNoUserSuppliedProxyInterfaces(config)) {
            Class targetClass = config.getTargetClass();
            if (targetClass == null) {
                throw new AopConfigException("TargetSource cannot determine target class: " +
                        "Either an interface or a target is required for proxy creation.");
            }
            if (targetClass.isInterface()) {
                return new JdkDynamicAopProxy(config);
            }
            if (!javassistAvailable) {
                throw new AopConfigException(
                        "Cannot proxy target class because Javassist is not available. " +
                                "Add Javassist to the class path or specify proxy interfaces.");
            }
            return new JavassistAopProxy(config);
        } else {
            return new JdkDynamicAopProxy(config);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Determine whether the supplied {@link AdvisedSupport} has only the
     * {@link org.springframework.aop.SpringProxy} interface specified
     * (or no proxy interfaces specified at all).
     */
    private boolean hasNoUserSuppliedProxyInterfaces(AdvisedSupport config) {
        Class[] interfaces = config.getProxiedInterfaces();
        return (interfaces.length == 0 || (interfaces.length == 1 && SpringProxy.class.equals(interfaces[0])));
    }

}
```

and i am getting error as

```
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: javassist.CannotCompileException: by java.lang.LinkageError: org.springframework.aop.framework.ProxyCreatorSupport
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JavassistApplicationContext.<clinit>
```

I tried adding  `cc.defrost();` and `cc.writeFile();` . i don't know why this exception coming .Is it a problem in the new method of class JavassistAopProxyFactory ?

```
c.insertAfter("$0.aopProxyFactory = new org.springframework.aop.framework.JavassistAopProxyFactory();");
```

And in `classpool.class` file , i can see the code

```
 public Class toClass(CtClass ct, ClassLoader loader, ProtectionDomain domain)
/*      */     throws CannotCompileException
/*      */   {
/*      */     try
/*      */     {
/* 1065 */       byte[] b = ct.toBytecode();
/*      */       Object[] args;
/*      */       Method method;
/* 1068 */       Object[] args; if (domain == null) {
/* 1069 */         Method method = defineClass1;
/* 1070 */         args = new Object[] { ct.getName(), b, new Integer(0), new Integer(b.length) };
/*      */       }
/*      */       else
/*      */       {
/* 1074 */         method = defineClass2;
/* 1075 */         args = new Object[] { ct.getName(), b, new Integer(0), new Integer(b.length), domain };
/*      */       }
/*      */       
/*      */ 
/* 1079 */       return toClass2(method, loader, args);
/*      */     }
/*      */     catch (RuntimeException e) {
/* 1082 */       throw e;
/*      */     }
/*      */     catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
/* 1085 */       throw new CannotCompileException(e.getTargetException());
/*      */     }
/*      */     catch (Exception e) {
/* 1088 */       throw new CannotCompileException(e);
/*      */     }
/*      */   }
/*      */
```

I am getting exception on line number `1085` .

I have researched some similar question from [Use javassist to modify fields that use getters and setters in a class constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13715986/use-javassist-to-modify-fields-that-use-getters-and-setters-in-a-class-construct) and [java javassist.CannotCompileException: by java.lang.LinkageError: loader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43846283/java-javassist-cannotcompileexception-by-java-lang-linkageerror-loader) . But still getting same problem . Any solution ?

Comment: I assume that you are aware that `$0` in Javassist is a special identifier. So what is supposes to mean the `$0.aopProxyFactory = ..`?

Comment: $0 is equivalent to this. If the method is static, $0 is not available

Comment: Did you try using `public void setAopProxyFactory(AopProxyFactory aopProxyFactory)` instead of assigning the value directly to the variable?

Comment: How can i do that ? can you please post a sample code ?

Answer (score 0):

I would try with changing the calls and set the factory with the internal setter:

```
package org.springframework.aop.framework;

import javassist.ClassPool;
import javassist.CtClass;
import javassist.CtConstructor;
import javassist.LoaderClassPath;
import org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext;

public class JavassistApplication extends XmlWebApplicationContext {

    public JavassistApplication(){
        ClassPool classPool = ClassPool.getDefault();
        try {
            // ClassLoader classLoader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
            // classPool.appendClassPath(new LoaderClassPath(classLoader));
            CtClass cc = classPool.get("org.springframework.aop.framework.ProxyCreatorSupport");
            /*modify the constructor body with java code*/
            CtConstructor c = cc.getConstructors()[0];
            c.insertAfter("setAopProxyFactory(new org.springframework.aop.framework.JavassistAopProxyFactory());");
             /*Here getting exceptions when i run*/
            cc.toClass();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new IllegalStateException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: should i assign this value again to aopProxyFactory ? like void `setAopProxyFactory(AopProxyFactory aopProxyFactory){this.aopProxyFactory = aopProxyFactory ;}` How can i declare this function definition ? can you please update the code .

Comment: just try the code like I posted and tell me what is the result

Comment: still getting same exception . Nothing has changed . `Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: javassist.CannotCompileException: by java.lang.LinkageError: org.springframework.aop.framework.ProxyCreatorSupport
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.JavassistApplication.<clinit>(JavassistApplication.java:36)`

Comment: Is there a reason on why you are doing this code in a `static` block or can you try to move it in a more canonical env? This is a `classloader` issue and I would say that my guess are that there are problem in static context with it

Comment: The error always pointing to `cc.toClass();` line . Still i am missing something ? or this is due to any class-loader error ?

Comment: if i remove static block and after i build with maven , i am getting `illegal start of type` error

Comment: Could you try to put the code in the constructor like I did in my code?

Comment: if i remove `static' only , i am getting another exceptions like `Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.aop.framework.JavassistApplication]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: javassist.CannotCompileException: by java.lang.LinkageError: org.springframework.aop.framework.ProxyCreatorSupport`

Comment: getting ` org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException : Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.aop.framework.JavassistApplication]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: javassist.CannotCompileException: by java.lang.LinkageError: org.springframework.aop.framework.ProxyCreatorSupport` still no luck !!

Comment: what is happening in `org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException ` exception ?

Comment: and for your information : this code was working fine with JDK 1.6 with WebSphere 8 . I was using Javassit 3.12.0GA

Comment: Can you add to your code the code for the class `org.springframework.aop.framework.JavassistAopProxyFactory()`?

Comment: I have added the code for `org.springframework.aop.framework.JavassistAopProxyFactory`

Comment: This error may happen when you link a library twice. Try to comment out the two lines about the class loader as I did.

Comment: After that also i am getting another exception  `Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: javassist.NotFoundException: org.springframework.aop.framework.ProxyCreatorSupport` and `Caused by: javassist.NotFoundException: org.springframework.aop.framework.ProxyCreatorSupport
        at javassist.ClassPool.get(ClassPool.java:450)'

Comment: Also `org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.aop.framework.JavassistApplication]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: javassist.NotFoundException: org.springframework.aop.framework.ProxyCreatorSupport`

Comment: getting javassist.NotFoundException: org.springframework.aop.framework.ProxyCreatorSupport exception .Any suggestions ?

Comment: it's ok . i have also tried different changes with respect to pom.xml  . also took different class loader trace too . still i am also out of control . If you have any other suggestion , don't forget to update . thanks man for your valuable time !!

Comment: I just want to know what is happening in cc.toClass(); ? you have any idea about it ?

Comment: I suggest you to focus on the java.lang.LinkageError and let the `cc.toClass` thing go 'cause it seems to me is just saying that this class cannot be compiled, hence there is an error in the code you are altering